# What is the proper explanation of compile time error of the following c program

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int f(int a)
{
  a > 20? return(10): return(20);
}
int main()
{
    int f(int);
    int b;
    b = f(20);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

I encountered following errors

expression syntax

function should return a value

parameter a is never used

Answer (score 3):

The conditional operator (`?:`) in C only takes expressions as operands.

Grammar from C99 §6.5.15:

> conditional-expression:
>   logical-OR-expression
>   logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression

A return statement is not an expression, it's a statement. So you cannot put a `return` statement in the operands.

You can rewrite your function with the following:

```
return a > 20 ? 10 : 20;
```

---

Side note. GCC (and clang, and possibly others) has an extension called [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) which you could use in this case to stuff a return statement in the conditional:

```
a > 20 ? ({return 10;}) : ({return 20;});
```

(I'm advocating doing that; but there might be uses for it.)

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

first, the source of your error, you're using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) wrong:

```
int f(int a)
{
  return (a > 20? (10): (20));
}
```

`a > b ? x : y` is going to return `x` or `y` to you, you can either store the value:

```
result = a > b ? x : y;
```

or in this case you can make the the return from the function.

Second this line:

```
int f(int);
```

is useless and should be removed

---

The reason that the way you were trying to do it is wrong is because the syntax of `?:` expects there to be an expression on the right hand side of the `?`

An expression in a programming language is a combination of explicit values, constants, variables, operators, and functions.

`return` is not an expressions, but a statement (a statement being the smallest standalone element of an imperative programming language.)

Thus you can `return` an expressions (the result of a ternary operation).

Comment: I agree with you but why can't I use 
a > 20? return(10): return(20); . In either case one return statement is going to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Correct implementation is as follows:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int f(int a)
{
  return a > 20? 10: 20;
}
int main()
{
    int f(int);
    int b;
    b = f(20);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mike and Hassan I need the explanation of my question. The correct explanation of error not the correct code.

Comment: Proper explanation is that int f(..) is returning integer however there is not last statement which returns integer. Remember that  a > 20? return(10): return(20); is the last statement and it does not start with return keyword.

Answer (score 0):

OP asked for explanation, not correction. Here is actual answer:

**expression syntax**: You've tried to use `return` statement as an argument of ?: operator. This 
fragment of code was erroneous, so compiler discarded it and continued compilation

**function should return a value** : because of first error, there was no valid `return` in function `f`

**parameter a is never used** : because of first error, parameter `a` is not used in function `f`